# How to ignore/prevent javadoc folder from validation during Eclipse Build?

Tags: eclipse, build

In my war is a huge javadoc folder. There is no point in validating it since javadocs are produced by Sun(Oracle) javadoc utility. I have forgotten how I did it the last time. I need to tell Eclipse build not to validate that particular folder.

Reasons why I need it:
1. the html produced by Sun javadoc generation utility does not meet the requirement that Eclipse uses - there is a bug report in Eclipse but Eclipse responds that Sun javadoc generator non-compliance is not their fault and that Eclipse intends to stick to their strict compliance. Which results in lots of html errors listed in the problems tab.
2. the javadoc folder is a remote link and high activity on that link is using up my cpu resource, and because it is a link to a remote location, that cpu high activity is sustained for long time until it finishes scanning the whole 35MB javadocs.

Thanks - need help.

Comment: Anyway, what would the "derived" option do when you click on the folder properties? When I set the derived option for a file, it seemed to do the trick with the following exception - when I do a manual build or when I reopen a closed project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you check the settings of [your validator](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/wst/components/validation/scenarios/validation_framework_testplan.html)

[image: Global Preferences]

it may have a setting allowing you to define an **Exclude Group** where you can add a rule to specify to exclude the validator for:

- specific extensions,
- folder or file name,
- project nature,
- facet or content type.

---

As the OP mentions in the comment, marking a folder as "derived" means it it will:

- not be build during incremental build
- only be build during full or manual build

As the [article mentions](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=0&uid=swg21221651):

> Derived resources are resources that are not original data, and can be recreated from their source files.  It is common for derived files to be excluded from certain kinds of processing.

Derived resources can influence [Eclipse Resource Filtering](http://www.mojavelinux.com/blog/archives/2006/03/eclipse_resource_filtering_using_derived/) as well:

> The trick is to open the "Navigator" view, right click on the folder to be ignored, and check the "Derived" property.
>   This option informs Eclipse that this folder consists of generated resources that should not be directly edited.
>   Once this is done, the "Open Resource..." view will only show matches that would be relevant to the developer.

Comment: Please respond to my comment on the "derived" option of a folder, which I placed as a comment under my question. thx.

Comment: @h2g2java: I have updated my answer to reflect the "derived folder" option.