# Configure Code Validation in Eclipse Galileo (3.5)?

Tags: java, eclipse, syntax-checking

In Eclipse Ganymede (3.4), you could navigate to:

> Window > Preferences > Validation

... and enable/disable various Validators. This feature seems to have disappeared in 3.5. **Was this feature moved/renamed/refactored? Where can I find it now?** I can't find any documentation pointing me to a new location.

This is what I'm expecting:

[image: Eclipse Validator Preferences]

This is what my Preferences window looks like:

[image]

I'm looking to disable several Validators, but the Seam Validator is my highest priority.

Comment: It should still be there (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616671/how-to-ignore-prevent-javadoc-folder-from-validation-during-eclipse-build/2616694#2616694) for Eclipse with WST (see http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/compare.php)

Comment: I added an additional screenshot of my own Eclipse (JEE) install.

Comment: Did you figure out what happened to your validators?

Comment: Nope, still no clue. I'm still going out of my way to stop validators I don't need as they try to run. As soon as all my necessary plugins are Helios compatible, I'm hoping that will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's here in my Galileo installation (and my Helios installation, too).  Class ValidationPreferencePage in plugin org.eclipse.wst.validation.ui.